# How can I run a command at the background without ampersand (&)?

Tags: command-line, bash, background-process

How can I run a command at the background in Bash without ampersand (&) at the end of a command?

**Update:**
I want to do it so I can do `while inotifywait -e modify app.py; do killall -9 python; python app.py &; done`, but that isn't possible because of the syntax.

Comment: Please [edit] and explain what you are trying to do. The `&` _is_ the way to run a command in the background. Why don't you want to use it? Do you want to send an already launched command to the background?

Comment: @Jos my `&` key isn't broken and @terdon I updated the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `coproc python app.py`

From `man bash`

> Coprocesses
>
> A  coprocess is a shell command preceded by the coproc reserved word.  A coprocess is executed asynchronously
>          in a subshell, as if the command had been terminated with the & control operator, with a two-way pipe  estab‐
>          lished between the executing shell and the coprocess.
>
> The format for a coprocess is:
>
> coproc [NAME] command [redirections]

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is slightly off:

```
while inotifywait -e modify app.py; do killall -9 python; python app.py &; done
```

It should be:

```
while inotifywait -e modify app.py; do killall -9 python; python app.py & done
```

Unlike C-like languages, you cannot have an empty statement before `;` or `&`.